# How to enable SSL debugging in Tomcat as a Windows service?

Tags: windows, debugging, tomcat, ssl, service

I have a java application (Jira) running in Tomcat on a Windows Server.
Tomcat is configured as a Windows service.

I tried to enable SSL debugging by configuring the Tomcat service JVM options (adding -Djavax.net.debug=all).
Java is a JRE7, but I tried also with JDK 7.

I see my JVM option in Jira start logs, but no SSL debug is shown, ever.

I really don't understand why this JVM option is not used by Java.

Does someone have an explanation/solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem and stumbled upon your question here.

I could get the SSL debug output by opening the tomcat service configuration (tomcatw.exe), going to the "Logging" tab and setting *Redirect Stdout* and *Redirect Stderror* to "*auto*"

Then it wrote those two files to the directory that is specified in *Log path* on the same tab.

I guess you could also pass those settings as parameters ([check here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html))

You might not need this any more, but maybe someone else has the same problem in the future.